# How could the economic cost of EORI number requirements in Europe be estimated?

Tags: international-trade

A friend recently tried to ship me my laptop from Romania (a EU member) to Montenegro (a EU candidate member). Even though neither of us is a business, and the laptop was mine and used, my friend had to apply for an [EORI](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/customs-4/customs-procedures-import-and-export-0/customs-procedures/economic-operators-registration-and-identification-number-eori_en), delaying the entire process by a number of days.

It seems that businesses aren't overly impacted by this requirement, as obtaining the EORI is a one-time process. For individuals though, the hassle can be significant, and as a EU resident, I was also forced to produce an EORI when receiving a package from the US.

The US has none of this, which may contribute to the perceived ease of doing business in the US.

How can the economic impact of the EORI number requirements be estimated?

Comment: in Germany I have never needed an EORI to receive a package from the US or anywhere else, though I do still need to declare what I am receiving and pay taxes. What are the customs procedures like in the US?

Comment: @user253751: in almost 20 years of living in the US, I never had to deal with any sort of customs. Small packages just showed up at my door, and occasionally I'd see larger ones (e.g. a Lenovo laptop) being detained in "customs" on its way to me.

Comment: big country privilege I suppose. Maybe the sender has to deal with  it